# Node.js and Express: "Cannot GET /" static site

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a small Node app and things were working fine. It needs to serve some static files from a directory `/source`.

Today, after a computer restart, when I visit my local site all I get is `Cannot GET /`. Nothing in the Node config has changed since it was working last.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    path    = require('path'),
    fs      = require('fs');

// Load our static site to start with
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'source')));

// Start the node server
app.listen(3000, function() {
  var host = this.address().address,
      port = this.address().port;

  console.log('Serving Atenium at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

My folders look like:

```
|- app/
|-- index.js
|- source/
|-- <static files>
```

Any ideas as to why this just stopped working?

Comment: is there a `source/index.html` file or anything?

Comment: Yes, the `source/` directory has an `index.html` file.

Comment: Could you please show where you have defined your routes?

Answer (score 0):

Could you have updated your express module in the process? I believe in Express 4, static content is now handled by the serve-static middleware library found here https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static .

Comment: There hasn't been an update. I'm using Express 4.11.2 and the code above used to work. I did try setting up `serve-static` and I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'source')));`

you have to create a virtual static path like:

`app.use('/source', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'source')));`